# Swap SVG icons in child themes

Tags: child-theme, icon, svg

The Twenty Nineteen theme uses inline SVG for its icons instead of icon fonts. The icons are added to the HTML code with the `TwentyNineteen_SVG_Icons::get_svg()` function.

```
public static function get_svg( $group, $icon, $size ) {
    if ( 'ui' == $group ) {
        $arr = self::$ui_icons;
    } elseif ( 'social' == $group ) {
        $arr = self::$social_icons;
    } else {
        $arr = array();
    }
    if ( array_key_exists( $icon, $arr ) ) {
        $repl = sprintf( '<svg class="svg-icon" width="%d" height="%d" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" ', $size, $size );
        $svg  = preg_replace( '/^<svg /', $repl, trim( $arr[ $icon ] ) ); // Add extra attributes to SVG code.
        $svg  = preg_replace( "/([\n\t]+)/", ' ', $svg ); // Remove newlines & tabs.
        $svg  = preg_replace( '/>\s*</', '><', $svg ); // Remove white space between SVG tags.
        return $svg;
    }
    return null;
}
```

When themes used icon fonts it was extremely easy to swap one icon for another with just a few lines of CSS code in a child theme. It seems that now with SVG icons one has to rewrite or override PHP functions just to add or swap one icon. Am I wrong? Is there an easy way to swap one SVG icon for another in a child theme of the Twenty Nineteen theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that both icon arrays (`$ui_icons` and `$social_icons`) in Twenty Nineteen can be accessed publicly, so I managed to replace any icon via the `init` hook in a child theme. An example:

```
function child_init() {
    TwentyNineteen_SVG_Icons::$social_icons['instagram'] = '<svg>... Insert new Instagram icon SVG code here ...</svg>';
}
add_action( 'init', 'child_init' );
```